# Syntactic sugar for creating new subclasses?

Tags: python, python-3.x

We are developing a library where we want to allow users to easily develop their own objects that can interact with the rest of the library.

To give a concrete example, the APIs we created so far use a similar implementation as the one used in scikit-learn for building custom estimators (see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#apis-of-scikit-learn-objects and https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460/sklearn/base.py#L141). There, users can create their own estimators by subclassing from `BaseEstimator` and implementing their own `fit` method.

Similarly, in our library we have a basic abstraction that constitutes the "building block" of the library. We have implemented our own `BaseClass` as an abstract class, with several methods `foo1`, `foo2` etc. already implemented, *and* an abstract method `bar` to be implemented by users:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class BaseClass(ABC):

    def foo1(self):
        pass

    def foo2(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass
```

`BaseClass` was designed so that it is sufficient for the user to implement their custom logic `bar` in order for the resulting object to be compatible with the rest of the library:

```
class CustomClass(BaseClass):

    def bar(self):
        # Concrete implementation of custom logic
        pass
```

Until here, everything works as expected (in fact, we implemented some custom classes ourselves in this way to distribute with the core library).

While this works well and it is already reasonably simple, we would like to make it even easier for users to integrate their custom logic with our library (possibly even in a notebook), so we were thinking of developing some "syntactic sugar" that would allow users to integrate with the library without explicitly defining any subclasses of `BaseClass`.

We were thinking of using a decorator to wrap a concrete implementation of `bar` for this, but we don't have an ideal solution yet. Our initial attempt does the following:

```
def decorator(subclass_name):
    def wrap(f):
        globals()[subclass_name] = type(subclass_name, (BaseClass,), {'bar': f})
        return f
    return wrap
        
@decorator('mySubclass')
def my_bar(self):
    pass
```

So, the decorator creates a subclass of `BaseClass` named `mySubclass`, implements the method `bar` using `my_bar`, and returns `my_bar`. We see 2 disadvantages with this approach:

1. `mySubclass` is created as a side-effect of using the decorator, which might make it not very intuitive and defeat the goal of being simple and intuitive to use;
2. The variable `mySubclass` is created from the string passed to the decorator by using `globals()[subclass_name]`, which might be an anti-pattern.

For these 2 reasons (there might be others of course), we are looking for alternatives. Is there any recommended approach for syntactic sugar for subclassing programmatically, with or without decorators?

EDIT: probably better to clarify that our plan is still to position "explicit subclassing" as the main reference API (fully documented) for implementing custom logic. The syntactic sugar would *not* replace it, but be there as a convenience feature for quick prototyping of simple custom logic.

The motivation behind it is that here the "custom logic" is actually a data processing step: the scenario is that users (e.g. data scientists) have already prototyped their own data processing logic in some notebook, and would like to quickly onboard it on our library. Instead of explicit subclassing, they might prefer to just embed the logic in a function and "run some magic" to get the object needed to interact with our library. So, it would be mostly about "giving users the choice".

Let me reiterate that we are not dead set on using decorators for this, it just seemed the most promising direction for the "magic" part :)

Comment: In my opinion, subclassing should _look like subclassing_ and thus involve the regular subclassing syntax. The user should know that they're creating a subclass of something. They should also be able to add their own methods to that class, which doesn't seem possible with any "syntactic sugar".

Comment: I prefer aggregation over inheritance. Also, with python it's easy to pass functions as parameters, and to bind parameters too.

Comment: Yeah, the syntactic sugar for creating subclasses is `class Subclass(Base class):...`

Comment: These are valid points, I added some clarifications on the motivation for this. About "being able to add their own methods to that class": I fully agree that, for nontrivial logic, direct subclassing is the way to go since it results in better and more readable code. If the logic of `bar` is trivial though, the user might not want to bother with subclassing. About "adding own methods with syntactic sugar": not possible in any language, but definitely possible in Python :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must agree with the commenters that just using the normal subclassing syntax would be best, but I still want to provide an example using decorators.
to avoid the issues you raised, why not just do what a normal decorator does and replace the function with something new (normally a new function wrapping the original, but we can make that a class!)

```py
def decorator(func):
    return type(func.__name__, (BaseClass, ), {'bar': func})

@decorator
def my_bar(self):
    print("test")

my_bar().bar() # output: test
```

Comment: I thought about this, but I felt uneasy about the undecorated function being a function and the decorated one being a class... It seemed counterintuitive to me and I feared it could be for users as well. I'm not that familiar with decorators though, so perhaps my expectations are wrong and it's not so strange that adding a decorator to a function might make it a class?

Comment: @hiryu It's no more counterintuitive than your current version which creates a new class and dynamically adds it to the global namespace. It sounds like you are trying to have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: it is not something that is done often, one example I can think of is [`discord.ext.commands.command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.command) that makes the function into an instance of `Command`, but that fact is very rarely used, or even known by the user

Comment: @juanpa didn't mean the opposite, the question also indicates that the current version _is_ counterintuitive. It might very well be that we can't have it all and do this with decorators without making some compromises, perhaps there is another way?

Comment: instead of a decorator it could be a normal function `myBarClass = magic_func(my_bar_function)`, which might be more intuitive. and they could also use it as a decorator if they wanted.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that as well, might be a better approach for this... But what do you mean by "use it as decorator if they wanted"?

Comment: @hiryu well, a decorator *is* a function. The `@foo` syntax is just syntactic sugar for `def func...` then `func = foo(func)`, so for example, you could already use `decorator('mySubclass')(my_bar)`

Comment: Sure, I don't know why I didn't see it!